# Printing the line number with eledpar in facing pages only on the left page, but not on the right one

Tags: double-sided, line-numbering, eledpar

I am editing an ancient poem with an apparatus criticus and my own prose translation of it. So I want the line numbers only on the leftpage (poetry), but not on the the right one. As far as I have seen, it is impossible to use the numbering only on one side, because I need `\beginnumbering \pstar \pend \endnumbering` on both pages for synchronization.
Is it possible to print the linenumbers only on one page?

Here is an example without critical note (to keep it short).

```
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\begin{flushleft}
\beginnumbering
\linenummargin{right}
\edef\marginnotetextwidth{\the\textwidth}
\pstart
\noindent\setline{1}
Senex fidelis, prima credendi uia\\
Abram, beati seminis serus pater,\\
adiecta cuius nomen auxit syllaba,\\
Abram parenti dictus, Abraham deo,\\
senile pignus qui dicauit uictimae  \\ 
docens, ad aram cum litare quis uelit,\\
quod dulce cordi, quod pium, quod unicum\\
deo libenter offerendum credito,\\
pugnare nosmet cum profanis gentibus\\
suasit suumque suasor exemplum dedit\\ 
nec ante prolem coniugalem gignere\\
deo placentem, matre uirtute editam,\\
quam strage multa bellicosus spiritus\\
portenta cordis seruientis uicerit.\\
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{flushleft}
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\selectlanguage{german}
\beginnumbering
\edef\marginnotetextwidth{\the\textwidth}
\pstart
\noindent\setline{1}
Der gläubige Alte, das erste Vorbild des Glaubens, Abram, erst spät Vater eines gesegneten Stammes, dessen Namen eine hinzugefügte Silbe vergrößert hat -- denn Abram wurde er von seinem Vater genannt, Abraham aber von Gott --, der das Pfand seines Alters zum Opfer geweiht hat und so gelehrt hat, dass, wenn jemand am Altar opfern will, er das, was seinem Herzen lieb und teuer, was fromm, was einzig ist, im Vertrauen auf Gott gerne darbringen soll, hat uns geraten, dass wir mit den gottlosen Völkern kämpfen, und hat als Ratgeber selbst sein Beispiel gegeben, dass wir keine eheliche Nachkommenschaft zeugen können, die Gott gefällt und von der Mutter "`Tugend"' hervorgebracht ist, bevor in großem Gemetzel der  kriegerische Geist die vielen Ungeheuer des versklavten Herzens besiegt hat. [1--14]
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
```

Answer (score 3):

You can tell you want to numbering right page only after a great, great number of line.

So do

```
\firstlinenumR{10000000}
```

Ps: if you start you project, you should move to reledmac/reledpar. eledmac/eledpar is not maintened anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this. This also solved my problem!