# Reledpar - Hide line numbering on one side of twoside translation

Tags: double-sided, reledmac, reledpar, parallel-texts

I am currently creating a Latex document in a twoside class which contains a bilingual text: On the left side (the left page) there is always a latin text and on the right side (the right page) there is the german translation. For this I am using reledpar and I am really happy with it, there is just one problem I have.

By default on the left side of the left page there is the line numbering and on the right side of the right page there is a line numbering for the right text followed by a capital R.
Now I want to keep the line numbering on the left page, but remove the line numbering on the right page completely (hide it).

I read through the reledpar / reledmac documentation but could not find help in there. I found out that with "\numberlinefalse" I can completely deactivate the line numbering on both sides but this is not what I want.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{scrbook}

% Synchronize text on multiple pages 
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

% Set space between pstart and pend
\AtEveryPstart{
    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
}

% Begin the document
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \input{LatinText}
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \input{GermanText}
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pages} 
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Inside of the LatinText and GermanText there is just a lot of "\pstart" and "\pend" with some text in between so nothing special.

TLDR: How can I remove the line numbering on one page of a twoside translation document using reledpar/reledmac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a look again at all similar reledpar questions I found this answer from [Maïeul](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7712/ma%C3%AFeul) ([Printing the line number with eledpar in facing pages only on the left page, but not on the right one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280180/printing-the-line-number-with-eledpar-in-facing-pages-only-on-the-left-page-but/280181#280181)) which solved my problem. Credits to him:

> You can tell you want to numbering right page only after a great,
>   great number of line.
>
> So do
>
> \firstlinenumR{10000000}

Answer from [Maïeul](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7712/ma%C3%AFeul)! Upvote him not me!